# Bootstrap multi column Responsive List Group with link

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the following Bootstrap List Group with link and badge on my website:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="/resources" class="list-group-item">
    Africa <span class="badge badge-default pull-right">4 offers</span>
  </a>
  <a href="/resources" class="list-group-item">
    More <span class="badge badge-default pull-right">14 offers</span>
  </a>
  <a href="/resources" class="list-group-item">
    Another <span class="badge badge-default pull-right">123 offers</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Is it possible to make this list list multi column ? I need it as 3 responsive equal columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is, this is why we use Bootstrap.

> **Bootstrap** includes a powerful **mobile-first** `flexbox` **grid system** for building **layouts** of all shapes and sizes.
>
> It’s based on a 12 column layout and has multiple tiers, one for each
>   media query range.
>
> You can use it with Sass mixins or our predefined classes.

[**Grid system**](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/)

---

```css
/*added posotion absolute to the badge  */
.badge {
    position: absolute;
    right: -15px;
}
list-group-item{
    position:relative;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<!-- using bootstrap grid system parent div is 12 columns -->
<div class="list-group col-lg-12">
<!-- using bootstrap grid system child div is 4 columns -->
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <a href="/resources" class="list-group-item">
    Africa <span class="badge badge-default pull-right">4 offers</span>
  </a>
 </div>
 <!-- using bootstrap grid system child div is 4 columns -->
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <a href="/resources" class="list-group-item">
    More <span class="badge badge-default pull-right">14 offers</span>
  </a>
 </div>
 <!-- using bootstrap grid system child div is 4 columns -->
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <a href="/resources" class="list-group-item">
    Another <span class="badge badge-default pull-right">123 offers</span>
  </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is interesting, I used this however I want only one column  appear on mobile devices, now all 3 columns appear. Stack om mobile devices ?

Comment: that is simple there is `col-lg-x` & `col-md-x` and `col-xs-x` and `col-xs-x`
the `x` is the number of columns you wana give to any element so , look at the code again, the `col-lg-12` would be for large screen and `col-md-12` would be for medium screen and `col-sm-4` for small device and `xs` for xstra smalls device

Comment: Thank you, i am going to learn Bootstrap now it was years ago when I used HTML. Things have change a lot since then :)